# How to deal with Sub Role in spring security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have one expert role in my Web Api.In expert there are 2 type of expert
 1 Expert one
 2 Expert Two

I should I check for it in Spring security.Both the expert are of type 2(id)  in data base.But there is one more table for expert type and where is it is defined as "Expert one"  and "Expert two".
Please help me how to deal with.
How can I send extra parameter and ask spring security to check

Comment: create different groups? Map users->role->groups

Comment: @sheetal Please can you explain in more detail??

Comment: Can you post the tables and explain your requirement more clearly? Add pics or DB and what really you want so people can suggest you best bit.

Comment: OK Thanks.....>i have roles Table which have 
ROLE_ID            
ROLE_DESCRIPTION
I have role id 2 and it is expertRole
I have 2 type of expert
For which I have ExpertType Table 
ID
NAME  .So I have 2 type of expert 1) expert one 2 Expert 2
Which ever Expert Login It should check for Expert role as well as expert type and than allow to access page.
How can I do this can you help